# In SPFx is it possible to check if we're getting data from a List or a Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, pnp

I use PnP in an SPFx web part. I'm wondering is it possible to know if its a Document Library or a List that's being access in `getByTitle`?

```
var colsToSelect = [
  "Title"
];

console.log('getTabData');

//const data: ITab[] = [];
let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
const items: any[] = await web.lists.getByTitle("ListOfLinks").items.select(...colsToSelect).get();
```

Comment: Hi Pete, what exactly is your requirement? What you want to do with the information whether its library or list?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap if it's a DL I want to select the FileRef column and then display the link to the file. If it's not I don;t want to select that column. Is there a way to select all the columns in the list / DL? Thanks for the help. P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the type of list while using `lists.getByTitle("<name>").items` endpoint.

You can identify the type of list based on it's `BaseTemplate` like below:

```
let colsToSelect: string[] = [];

const r = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle(listName).select("BaseTemplate")();

if (r.BaseTemplate === 101) {
  console.log("It's a document library");
  colsToSelect.push("FileRef");
} else {
  console.log("It's a list");
  colsToSelect.push("Title");
}
```

You can find other `BaseTemplate` enum values at: [ListTemplateType enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541191(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.